# Optional GET parameter

Tags: c#, razor

i have 3 pages/sites: a startpage, a productspage and a layoutpage.
on each page i have at the top a navbar: with Start(brings you to the startpage) and a dropdown-menu with an "all products"-element.
[image]
if you click on "all Products" you are directed to the Products-Page(products.cshtml).

the products.cshtml (page) should receive an optional GET-parameter "category" (type=string). if this parameter was entered , it should show only products, which has the category out of the string.
e.g. string=seafood => only show products from category=seafood

my code so far in my layout.cshtml:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li method="get" name="kategorie" target="_blank" >
<a href="~/Produkte.cshtml">Alle Speisen</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

i don't know how i declare that the GET-parameter is optional and how to declare that only products from the category in the string should be shown.

sorry for poor english

Comment: i can't unserstand properly.
as per my understand you want ..., you have dropdown of category and if you select any category from dropdown , you redirect to product page according your selected category.. m i right?

Comment: @Mohit Solanki i edited it i hope the understanding is now better

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to display a list of meals in a menu, you can separate the list from the UI and then make an entry for each entry in the menu. Here is a small example:

**Model Class:**

```
public class MealsViewModel
{
   public string Category {get; set;}
   public string DisplayName {get; set;}
   public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller Methode:**

```
 public ActionResult index(string category)
{
  var model = GetListofMeals(category);
  model.insert(0, new MealsViewModel(){ id=0, DisplayName="Alle Speisen", Category = ""}; 
  return View(model);
}


public ActionResult Products(int id)
{
  var model = GetMeal(id);
  return View(model);
}

private List<MealsViewModel> GetListofMeals(string category)
{
  ......
}

private MealsViewModel GetMeal(int id)
{
   .......
}
```

**Index View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.MealsViewModel>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach(var meal in Model)
{
<li>
 @Html.ActionLink(Model.DisplayName, "products", new { id = Model.id}, new { target ="_blank"})
</li>
}
</ul>
```

Viel Spaß bei Ausprobieren ;)

> Have fun trying out